# How can I disable GNOME keyring for svn?

Tags: keyrings, gnome-keyring

I have tried several methods to disable GNOME keyring, but have had no success so far. I have removed `gnome-keyring` already using the following command:

> sudo aptitude remove gnome-keyring

I have also tried this:

> rm /home/username/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring

But yet, whenever I try to use svn, I am asked for GNOME keyring password:

> Password for 'default' GNOME keyring:

What else should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit the `~/.subversion/config` with gedit or nano , and add the following lines

```
[auth] 
password-stores =
```

then save it and try again.

Comment: `chmod: cannot access ‘/usr/bin/gnome-keyring’: No such file or directory`

Comment: search for startup applications in dash and then uncheck the gnome-keyring

Comment: I've already done that. GNOME-keyring is unchecked.

Comment: i updated my ans.

Comment: ``/nas/user/.subversion/config:2: Option expected``

Comment: @User1291 leading spaces did produce that error for me. try to remove them.